# Finding the maximum value of algebraic expression

Tags: maxima-minima

What is the maximum value of

> $(ax+b)^\frac12 + (cx+d)^\frac12$

I did it using the concept $AM>=GM$

$\frac{(ax+b)^\frac12+(cx+d)^\frac12}2 \geq ((ax+b)^\frac12(cx+d)^\frac12)^\frac12$

And on solving this I found that $x\leq(b-d)/(c-a)$

And when $x$ is maximum value of the expression will be maximum

But this was not the answer. Somebody help me, please.

Comment: Did you try with algebra ?

Comment: Do you mean the *minimum* value when $x \in \mathbb R$? Or is there some restriction on $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: Consider the function $$f(x)=\sqrt{ax+b}+\sqrt{cx+d}$$ and differentiate with respect to $x$

Comment: Differentiation gives minima

Comment: if $a,b>0$ then $ (ax+b)^\frac12 + (cx+d)^\frac12$ is not bounded and increasing so it does not make sense to look for a maximum value.